# phpMyAdmin trying to input database, file too big

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a database that is 9,451 KB and 1,933 KB zipped up. When I try to import this database I get this error: `You probably tried to upload too large file. Please refer to documentation for ways to workaround this limit.`

I have tried setting the following settings and restarted my local machine and I still get the same error:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100000000000000000000000000000M
memory_limit = 10000000000000000000000000000000000000M
post_max_size = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000M

max_execution_time = 5000000000000
max_input_time = 500000000000
```

What Am I doing wrong :(

Comment: do you have command line access to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, there are lot of `0s` in your settings!!
You don't require such high allocations. Keep the default settings.

Just change `upload_max_filesize = 64M` and `post_max_size = 64M`

Now, getting to the point. Why you problem still persists.

1. You modified the wrong php.ini file. Check if there's another php.ini file in the system.
2. You don't require to restart your whole machine. Simply restarting the server would be enough.

Try these and see if it works out!

Answer (score 0):

The [phpMyAdmin documentation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems) also has some additional hints, solutions, and workarounds.